# Margin-Top Menu not Working

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rae9m/

And as you can see, the menu at the top doesn't want to stick to the margin top as expected. Here's my HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="menu">
<div class="item">Page</div>
<div class="item">Page</div>
<div class="item">Page</div>
<div class="item">Page</div>
</div>
<h2>Blue Beat</h2>
<div class="desc">
<em style="color: #00F7FF">Blue Beat - Featuring Electric Blue Color</em>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS is quite big so I'll put the important part here:

```
.menu {
width: 1000px;
}

.menu:last-child {
float: clear;
}

.item {
width: 250px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background-color: #00F7FF;
transition: background-color 1s;
}

.item:hover {
transition: background-color 1s;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Any ideas for why this doesn't work ? I tried it all, `margin-top: 0` for body, menu, container divs and so on, still not working, it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it the `<h2>` that is giving you this space. Default h2

Css:

```
h2 {margin:0;}
```

**[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rae9m/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing your floats in the `.menu` properly.

If you change

```
.menu:last-child {
    float: clear;
}
```

to

```
.menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

or similar, you can keep the margin on your headings without them spilling out of the container. http://jsfiddle.net/Rae9m/6/